# How does one install Jekyll subcommands?

Tags: jekyll

I got the error:

```
fatal: 'jekyll page' could not be found. You may need to install the jekyll-page gem or a related gem to be able to use this subcommand.
```

how do I install subcommands?

---

https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/how-to-install-subcommands/3500

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
gem install jekyll-page
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work:

```
# Seems this is needed to install a lot of subcommands, see: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-compose
gem 'jekyll-compose', group: [:jekyll_plugins]
```

add it to ur Gemfile and then bundle install it with

```
bundle
```